# Save post meta and reuse them

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

So I have two files (Read the "**`Edit: Clarification`**" at the bottom first)

**`first.php`:**

```
<div class="rfp_hide " >
    <?php   
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'paged'=>$paged,
        'posts_per_page' => 15,         
        'orderby' => 'date',            
        'order' => 'DESC'
        );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    $id = get_the_ID();     
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    ?>

     <?php the_title(); ?>
     <?php the_content(); ?>
     <?php echo '<button class="button" data-post_id="' .$id. '">' ;?>
         <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rh_type', true); ?>   
     <?php echo '</button>';?>  
     <div class="new_content">
          <!--Ajax new content goes here-->
     </div>
 </div>
```

So this will display posts with `title`, `content`, `button` with a custom meta ("rh_type"). When the button is clicked, it loads another file (`second.php`) via ajax as below within `new_content` div.

**Second.php**

```
 <div class="second_content">
     <?php the_title(); ?>
     <?php the_content(); ?>
     <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rh_type', true); ?>   
 </div>
```

In other words, when the `button` is clicked from the `first.php`, then the `second.php` will be loaded within the `new_content` div.
Once it is loaded, I want to make it so that the same `title`, `content`, and the `custom meta` as the `first.php` are displayed.

**However here is the problem.**

Because the `meta` in the `second.php` are not originally part of the loop (meaning, it is outside of the loop), even though it is loaded within the loop once the button clicked, it does not display any of the `post meta`.

I am not sure what the best approach is to "`extend`" the loop, here is my approach.

**APPROACH:**

1. Every posts will have its own unique `post_id`, and buttons will also have the `post_id` with them.
2. When the button is clicked, save the `post_id` (I am guessing with jQuery) along with other meta data (title, etc).
3. Once the `second.php` is loaded, then `load` or `paste` these saved meta data to an appropriate place.

This approach might work, but I am not sure how to accomplish them.

Any help will be much appreciated it.

Thanks!

**EDIT: Clarification**

The question above is simplified version of what I have, in order to avoid the confusion.

So, here is what I am trying to achieve.

1. There are 10 posts displayed in a page.
2. Each posts have a button to call "contact_form.php" via ajax.
3. Once the button is clicked, then the contact form is shown.
4. The contact form has typical input fields such as name, email, etc.
5. Once these are filled out, then is submitted.

So far so good.

When I receive the email, then the problem occurs.

I have no idea which post the contact form was sent from.

So, my approach (or trying to make it work) is to somehow save the post meta of which the button was clicked, then "paste" these data onto the contact form, so that when I receive the email, I know which content it is from.

Comment: No clear from your question, but why are you using `$post->ID` inside your WP_Query loop. You have to use `get_the_ID()`. And please try to explain your question clearly. Not getting anything clearly.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I added "Edit: Clarification" section at the bottom. =)

Comment: So you need to pass the current post id on button click so you get that post id in contact form. And inside your contact form pass that id (or get the post name,id, etc from post_id) to e-mail content.

Comment: Mhmm, that is exactly it! :D

Comment: So finally you got the solution?

Comment: Well, no,, haha. I am not sure how to save the post meta through jQuery then show on the "second.php"..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89558/discussion-between-kausha-mehta-and-steve-kim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally finding the solution. For seeing Solution you can check here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89558/discussion-between-kausha-mehta-and-steve-kim

Comment: mhmm! =) Thank you. I got it working and learned something more today!